# Working with PowerShell v2 : Remote info from server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a question i'm trying to basically write a script to gather server roles information remotely from my pc. i have administrative rights not the server since its just a dummy test server.

What i currently have is the initial cmd :

```
servermanagercmd.exe -query roles.xml
```

What i need help understanding is :

- How to initialize a connection to the server (My server is a MS 08 R2 64-bit) with remoting enabled.
  via Enable -PSRemoting -Force. "As i'm sure i need to pass my login info in the cmd some how to be allowed to run the cmd im passing.
- Sending the cmd to the server servermanagercmd.exe -query roles.xml

Comment: What you are looking for is the Invoke-Command cmdlet. Type 'Get-Help Invoke-Command -Full' in your PowerShell window to get all the details.

Comment: Lol thank you, i managed to figure it out :)